# appendingPathComponent: does not do percentage encoding resulting in load failures in swift 3

Tags: ios, url, swift3, xcode8.2

In swift 3 i am Using alamofire for network calls . For this i am appending Base URL with the string.Because of which i am getting the response as nil. Please find the code below:

```
public var baseURL: URL { return URL(string: "http://138.112.175.138:3300/api")! }

    public var path: String {
    switch self {

    case .carsSearch:
      return "/cars/display?model=1"

    default:
      return ""
    }
  }
```

For appending this :

```
    public func url() -> String {
    return self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent(self.path).absoluteString
  }
```

But i am getting the output as :

**http://138.112.175.138:3300/api/cars/display%3Fmodel=1**

Because of this my response is getting nil. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove persent encoding:

```
public func url() -> String {
    return self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent(self.path).absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding
  }
```